# Can anyone explain the given lines in htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

In my .htaccess file there are few lines like given below.

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"

ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"

I want to know do the first two lines and last two lines are doing the same thing? Also want to know can If both are doing the same can i remove the last two lines then?

Comment: Wait, did you write the code in the .htaccess file? If yes then why ask this question? You should know the meaning of the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is "access plus [time]". So the last two lines "do" the same as the first two, although the first two lines aren't formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [ExpiresByType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresbytype)  directive  to add expiration date to cached contents in users browser. For example, when someone tries to get  a gif image from your website, the directive below, tells Apache to add  `Expires` header to response,therefore , the browser will cache the file for one year

```
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
```